# Pyspark select date1 col value closest to date2 value, preference given to date1 if it is less than date2, groupby ID

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is the logic in SQL:

```
coalesce(if effc_dt <= tran_dt select(max of effc_dt) , if effc_dt >= tran_dt select (min of effc_dt))
```

I want similar logic in Pyspark, when `effc date` is lesser than `tran date` it will select `effc date` closest to `tran date` and if lesser date is not present it will check for greater and select `effc date` closest to `tran date`.

Input dataframe:

```
|id|tran_date  |effc_date  |
|--|-----------|-----------|
|12|2020-02-01 |2019-02-01 |
|12|2020-02-01 |2018-02-01 |
|34|2020-02-01 |2021-02-15 |
|34|2020-02-01 |2020-02-15 |
|40|2020-02-01 |2019-02-15 |
|40|2020-02-01 |2020-03-15 |
```

Expected Output:

```
|id|tran_date  |effc_date  |
|--|-----------|-----------|
|12|2020-02-01 |2019-02-01 |
|34|2020-02-01 |2020-02-15 |
|40|2020-02-01 |2019-02-15 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by id and tran_date, then do a coalesce of conditional aggregations:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.groupBy('id', 'tran_date').agg(
    F.coalesce(
        F.max(F.when(F.col('effc_date') < F.col('tran_date'), F.col('effc_date'))), 
        F.min(F.when(F.col('effc_date') >= F.col('tran_date'), F.col('effc_date')))
    ).alias('effc_date')
)

df2.show()
+---+----------+----------+
| id| tran_date| effc_date|
+---+----------+----------+
| 12|2020-02-01|2019-02-01|
| 34|2020-02-01|2020-02-15|
| 40|2020-02-01|2019-02-15|
+---+----------+----------+
```